# .txt with windows activation (Batch file)

Tags: windows, batch-file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLKZH.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1BlQ.jpg)Im fairly new to serious batch files. But i have a problem I'm sure can be solved with coding. i am in charge of keeping 100+ units product keyed, And we have to change them out when they go bad , but sometimes they don't get re-keyed so i'm trying to find a way to keep track of non activated windows units.

Before you ask no we don't have a volume license server, or anything related to that unfortunately. my boss is old school.

So i have a code that has:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (computers.txt) do shutdown -r -t 0 -m %%i// and that works fine and restarts all pcs i have in the .txt file in ip address form. then i run around trying to catch all the activation windows before they dissapear. but im trying to get it to check windows activation and output that to a text file with all the units that are NOT activated.  

@echo off
for /f %%i in (computers.txt) do cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr > ActivatedStatus.txt | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (echo Not permanently activated.) else (echo Permanently activated)
pause
exit /b
```

It works fine and checks the local pc im on but i just cant get it to push the command to a given set of ip addresses. any help would be greatly appreciated. been borrowing snipets of code from here to make this. figured it was time for help.

Comment: Why do they "go bad"? This shouldn't happen. Are the computers member of a domain, and are you a domain administrator? I am asking because normal Windows administration in an enterprise context is through group policies and login scripts.

Comment: bad screen, ram fail, bad hdd.. ect. then get replaced with spares we have but the spares are not product keyed yet. not on a domain. and not an admin just an I.T grunt. we just have a bunch of pcs on the same network. 172.32.5.1,  .2, .3 ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target OS is `Windows 7` or newer, perhaps something along these lines may help you out:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "XSL=csv"
For /F "EOL=MDelims=" %%A In ('"WMIc OS Get MUILanguages,Version"'
) Do For /F Tokens^=2^,4-5Delims^=.^"^  %%B In ("%%A"
) Do If %%C Equ 6 If %%D Equ 1 Set "XSL=%__APPDIR__%WBEM\%%B\%XSL%
WMIC /Output:Results.log /Node:@Computers.txt Path SoftwareLicensingProduct^
 Where "PartialProductKey Is Not Null And Name Like 'Windows(R)%%' And Not LicenseStatus='1'"^
 Get LicenseStatus,Name,ProductKeyID /Format:"%XSL%"
```

The idea is that it will check each of the Computers listed one per line in file named `computers.txt` in the current working directory. If the `Windows(R)` product is not showing as licensed, *(i.e. `1`)*, it should output some pertinent information to a file named `Results.log` also in your current working directory.

*The License Status output would translate to one of the following:*

> `0`: Unlicensed
>   `1`: Licensed
>   `2`: OOB Grace
>   `3`: OOT Grace
>   `4`: Non-Genuine Grace
>   `5`: Notification
>   `6`: Extended Grace

***Note:*** You may not need lines `3`-`5` of the script above if you're not checking from a `Windows 7` machine, I added those because of a known issue with the location of the `csv.xsl` file on versions of that OS.

Comment: That's what i need, thank you so much. I am running it from WIn 7 Pro. But i am getting an output that wasn't expected. When running my restart file that uses the computers.txt it works fine. but now im getting "No Instances Avaliable" will add pictures to the post for clarification.

Comment: We would need to see exactly the content of your script as it now looks, you should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54274503/edit)  and add it to the bottom.